# Is there an analogous method of finding moment for inelastic bending like in the case of inelastic torsion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

When calculating for Torque in torsion or for Moment in the case of bending, the concept is usually first introduced with the simplification of the assumption that the stresses and strains are in the elastic region of the material, appended by perfect elasto-plastic assumption of the material. And later for the same calculations in the case of the inelastic torsion the operation was to find the region upto which the material remained elastic and divvy the cross-section into two and calculate separately.

For torsion

T <sub>Total</sub> =T <sub>Elastic_Region</sub> + T <sub>Plastic_Region</sub>

In the Elastic region the Elastic torsion formula is applicable and for the Plastic region the constant stress is integrated over the whole area of the plastic region.
Can we do something similar for the case of inelastic bending too ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it may not be particularly helpful.

In the uniform-torsion case, an outer region of each and every cross-section yields, and the inner region doesn't. This case allows a relatively simple analysis.

In the beam-bending case, regions of different sizes and different fractions of the cross-section yield while moving down the length of the beam:

[image]

Say, for example, that the deep-purple and deep-red regions have yielded. If this aids analysis, it's certainly a reasonable idea to try to model this effect, perhaps as a beam with narrowing elastic cross-section near the midpoint. Know what I mean?